# Integration By parts for Lebesgue integrals

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Given bounded distribution functions $F$ and $G$, on $[a,b]$, such that $F$ and $G$ do not share a common point of discontinuity, following is true.

$$\int_{(a,b]} FdG +\int_{(a,b]}GdF\\ = F(b)G(b)-F(a)G(a)$$

I was able argue it using Fubini's theorem, what I don't understand is where does the condition "no common points of discontinuity" play into all this.

Comment: If you show how you proved it we can point out where you need the hypothesis about continuity points.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, a more general result is true (I'm going off memory, so I'd highly recommend you verify this closely). Given $F,G:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ right continuous and of bounded variation, define
\begin{align}
F_-(x):=\lim_{y\to x^-}F(y)\quad \text{and} \quad \Delta F(x):= F(x)-F_-(x),
\end{align}
and likewise for $G$. Then, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{(a,b]}F_-\,dG + \int_{(a,b]}G_-\,dF &= (FG)(b)-(FG)(a)-\int_{(a,b]}\Delta F\, dG\\
&=(FG)(b)-(FG)(a)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Delta F(x_n)\cdot \Delta G(x_n),
\end{align}
where $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is the set of discontinuities of $F$. The proof is almost identical to what you claim: apply Fubini to a carefully chosen subset of the plane (you just have to be more careful). So, from this you can see that if $F$ and $G$ are both discontinuous at a common point then you'll pick up an extra term.

Sorry this is slightly indirect; but to get a more direct answer, you'll have to show us precisely the proof you've seen so that we can point out exactly where the assumption is being used. It all boils down to the fact that the Stieltjes measures of singleton sets are non-zero at points of discontinuity:
\begin{align}
\mu_F(\{x\})&=\Delta F(x).
\end{align}

Comment: Could you please tell me where I can find a proof of this result?

Comment: @hh11apples I don't know of a proper reference; I remember proving something like this when I first read the integration by parts theorem you mention and decided to drop the continuity hypothesis. Just imitate the FUbini style proof you already know; follow it line by line and don't use any continuity assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try it out