# Resnick - Probability Path - Exercise 5.17

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Resnick (*A Probability Path*, 5.10.17) asks to show the following formula for two distribution functions $F$ and $G$ with no common discontinuity points in the interval $(a,b]$:
$$\int_{(a,b]} G(x) F(dx) = F(b)G(b) - F(a)G(a) - \int_{(a,b]} F(x)G(dx) $$
where the integrals are Lebesgue-Stieljes integrals.

I believe the key thing is to use Fubini's theorem, and here was my attempt at a solution:

\begin{align*}
\int_{(a,b]} G(x) F(dx) &= \int_{(a,b]} (G(x) - G(a)) F(dx) + \int_{(a,b]} G(a) F(dx)\\
  &= \int_{(a,b]} \int_{(a,b]} \mathbf{1}_{\{ a \le y \le x \le b \}}(y,x) G(dy) F(dx) +F(b)G(a)-F(a)G(a)\\
  &= \int_{(a,b]} \int_{(a,b]} \mathbf{1}_{\{ a \le y \le x \le b \}}(y,x) F(dx) G(dy) +F(b)G(a)-F(a)G(a)\\
  &= \int_{(a,b]} (F(b) - F(y)) G(dy) +F(b)G(a)-F(a)G(a)\\
  &= F(b)G(b) - F(b)G(a) + F(b)G(a) - F(a)G(a) - \int_{(a,b]} F(y)G(dy)
\end{align*}
where I used Fubini's theorem in the third equality.

However, Resnick states that this formula can fail if there are common discontinuity points, and I did not explicitly make use of this in my solution. Is that condition necessary in order to make the indicator function I use measurable/well-defined or to use Fubini's theorem? Or is my approach completely off-base?

Comment: I found the same question from a couple years ago, but the answer is kind of unhelpful (or I'm too stupid to understand it). My question is more specific as it relates to my solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4045593

Comment: To avoid mistakes, expand $(\mu_F \times \mu_G)(\{(x, y) : a < x \leq y \leq b\}$ two different ways using Fubini's theorem, then equate them. Notice the $a < x$ not $a \leq x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any assumptions on $F$ and $G$, if you expand $(\mu_F \times \mu_G)(\{(x, y) : a < x \leq y \leq b\})$ two ways using Fubini's theorem and equate them, you get
$$\int_{(a, b]}F(x)\,dG(x) + \int_{(a, b]}G(x-)\,dF(x) = F(b)G(b) - F(a)G(a).$$
Now under the assumption of no common discontinuity points, we need to show that $\int_{(a, b]}(G(x-) - G(x))\,dF(x) = 0$. Let $D(G)$ be the at most countable set of discontinuity points of $G$ on $(a, b]$. We have
$$\int_{(a, b]}(G(x-) - G(x))\,dF(x) = \sum_{x \in D(G)}\mu_F\{x\}=\sum_{x \in D(G)}(G(x-) - G(x))(F(x) - F(x-)) = 0$$
since $F(x) - F(x-) \neq 0$ iff $x$ is a discontinuity point of $F$.